# Linear equations system with parameter and conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{5×5}$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$

Given the following linear equations system
$Ax=\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ -1\\a^2+a\\1\\-1 \end {pmatrix} $

The genral solution is $\begin {pmatrix} t+u+1 \\ s+t-u\\s-t+1\\-s-t+u\\-s-u-1 \end {pmatrix} $

Also, the following vectors $\in Col A:$ $ \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\1\\0\\a^2-3 \end {pmatrix} $ $ \begin {pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\1\\-1\\a^2-2 \end {pmatrix} $

I had to find such $\alpha$ that fit all the information above and I found that $\alpha=0,-1$ now I need to find which value is still correct if we add the following statement: $A^2=0$ I have no idea how this extra demand affecting please help me

Comment: **Hint:** $A^2 = 0$ if and only if $Av = 0$ for every $v \in \operatorname{Col}(A)$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this statement, can you explain it?

Comment: Are you saying that you don’t understand my statement and want me to rephrase it, or are you asking me to prove the statement?

Comment: I'm asking for proof

Answer (score 0):

First, note that because $A^2 = 0$, $Av = 0$ for every $v \in \operatorname{Col}(A)$. Indeed, if $v \in \operatorname{Col}(A)$, then $v = Ax$ for some vector $x$, which means that
$$
Av = A(Ax) = A^2 x = 0x = 0.
$$
On the other hand, note that the general solution to the equation given is of the form
$$
x = x_0 + sv_1 + tv_2 + uv_3,
$$
which means that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ span the nullspace of $A$. So, if $A$ satisfies $A^2 = 0$, then the given vectors from the $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ must lie within the span of $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

Comment: Thanks I completely understand but one thing is how can I prove your first statement?

Comment: @3xhaust The sentence starting "Indeed, if..." is a proof of the statement.